# Why is writing on auto mounted partition not possible?

Tags: permissions, automount

Despite it has *rw* option. An extraction of fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/0109cc2c-414c-42dc-8a99-3ffe529020fe /mnt/0109cc2c-414c-42dc-8a99-3ffe529020fe auto rw,exec,noatime,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

This entry was created by the standard drives tool of lxde on debian.

Comment: what makes you think it is unwriteable? do you have read permission to the entire path of the mount point, and write permission to the target directories you wish to write to?

Comment: I have no write permission. It's a new drive and I can't copy or save any files on it.

Comment: did  you format it? your disk ID is pointing to a partition, right? Just for terminologies sake, permissions refers to files system permissions where as the `rw` option on the mount is its Mode.

Comment: thanks @Frank now I understand (didn't know that). See my answer which I just remembered from another situation with USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the owner by:

```
sudo chown -R userme:userme /mnt/fb7bd4xxxxxxxxxx
```

It might have happend since the partion was used before from a nother debian linux which I tried but deleted (by installing a new one).

Comment: gotcha. yeah this is a common problem when a disk from an older build was has contents that were owned by a non-root account (root is usually fine because the UID and GID for root are always the same).